# Send/receive data from one class to another

Tags: qooxdoo

Let's say :

```
qx.Class.define( 'App.Dlg1', { extend : qx.ui.window.Window, 
construct : function()
{
...
},
members :
{
    myFunc1 : function()
    {
    }
}
} )
```

and

```
qx.Class.define( 'App.Dlg2', { extend : qx.ui.window.Window, 
construct : function()
{
...
},
members :
{
myFunc2 : function()
    {
    }
}
} )
```

Both classes are different files, how can send-recieve data between those classes, I need to send some info from myFunc2() to myFunc1(), is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the two classes are related, you can use events, and have an instance of one class listen for an event that you fire by an instance of the other class.

It sounds, though, like you're thinking of unrelated instances. In that case, a useful qooxdoo feature is the message bus.

In Dlg1, for example, you might do the following, to await messages of type "dialog.data" (an arbitrary string, although the message bus some special wildcard properties available if there are dot-separated fields in the type):

```
var messageBus = qx.event.message.Bus.getInstance();

messageBus.subscribe(
  "dialog.data",
  function(busMessage)
  {
    var message = busMessage.getData();

    console.log("a=" + message.a);
  },
  this);
```

Then, in Dlg2, you can dispatch a message on the bus like so, which will cause the subscriber in Dlg1 to display `a=23`:

```
var messageBus = qx.event.message.Bus.getInstance();

messageBus.dispatchByName(
  "dialog.data",
  {
    a : 23
  });
```

Comment: Derrell, you are my hero from now on ;)  it works like a charm !!! thank you very much, save me tons of work ( and code ). Muchas Gracias.